# Moving the icon button to the right causes rendering issues

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to align the `IconButton` to the right of the `TextField`, I tried the `Row` which made the `IconButton` not centered vertically and now I am trying out the `Stack` widget.

Here is my code:

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Image.asset(
      'assets/images/phone_number.png',
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      opacity: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(.5),
    ),
    Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
      children: [
        IntlPhoneField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Lets start with your phone number',
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 1.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          color: Colors.green,
          iconSize: 90,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
          onPressed: () => nextScreen(2),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

UPDATE - 23/05/2023

Seyit - Your answer was my first attempt at this. The issue I had with that setup was the icon button was not centered horizontally.

The second option I tried which is the code above was able to center everything horizontally but was not able to push the `IconButton` to the far right.

The first one is with the `Row` and the second one is with the `Stack` widget.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that you are trying to place two widgets in a horizontal alignment, one of which is a `TextField`. The `TextField`, by its nature, tries to occupy the entire horizontal space, pushing the other element you added out of the screen and causing an error. To resolve this issue, you can use a simple technique called the `Expanded` widget. With the `Expanded` widget, you can determine how much space each widget can occupy within a `Row` or `Column`.

Here is an example code:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Text("First Item"),

    // PhoneField and IconButton
    Row(
      children: [
        const Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: TextField(
            // IntlPhoneField is also a TextField
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ), // end of the row 

    Text("Last Item"),
  ],
),
```

By enclosing the `TextField` and `IconButton` widgets with `Expanded`, you ensure that they share the horizontal space. The `TextField`, inside the `Expanded` with a flex value of 3, will take up 3 units of width, while the `IconButton`, inside the `Expanded` with a flex value of 1, will take up 1 unit of width. As a result, the two widgets will be aligned side by side.

**UPDATE - 24.05.2023**

The reason for this might be the character count below the `TextField`. It extends the area a bit, and even though the `IconButton` is actually centered, it seems to be slightly lower.

In this case, you can apply various solutions. For example, you can wrap the `IconButton` widget inside a `Column` widget, and then add a `SizedBox` inside this `Column`. This way, you can balance the space occupied by the maxLength counter.

`IconButton` widget:

```dart
Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        iconSize: 90,
        color: Colors.green,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_right,
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 20),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: centered IconButton]

I hope this helps

Comment: Seyit, I have added comments to the original post.

Comment: You are right, it was the character count that was causing alignment issues. Thanks Seyit.